# Macro to take a character as argument, make it active, then \def it.

Tags: macros, catcodes, parameters

I have a XeLaTeX document in which I want some unicode symbols to be auto-substituted, like ¼ → 1/4, » → >>, « → <<. But instead of a long list like

```
\catcode`\¼=\active\def¼{1/4}
\catcode`\«=\active\def«{<<}
...
```

I want something more elegant, like

```
\subst¼{1/4}
\subst«{<<}
\subst—{---}
```

So, I need a macro which will take two parameters, make #1 active, and \def it with #2. The first part was easy:

```
\def\subst#1#2{
  \catcode`#1=\active
  ...
}
```

The tricky part is the nested \def: no matter how I try, I cannot come up with anything working. The closest I got so far is defining commands like \¼ with

```
\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}
```

Which is of course not sufficient :)

How do I make it define those newly-made-active characters?

Comment: Normally people want the reverse substitutions, like `<<` → `«` :-)

Comment: Did you tested this using `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov In fact, what I need to do is check whether the font used in document does provide those tricky symbols (like ⅕, which is not in every font), and if not, substitute them with some kind of "emulation".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{¼}{1/4}
\newunicodechar{«}{<<}
\newunicodechar{—}{---}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's not exactly what I needed (my above example is a bit oversimplified), but I believe I found the clue to how to do it in that package's source.

Comment: Does this work with PDFLaTeX or does it require XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Sergey: if you feel it can be of general interest, you should add the case to the question, so maybe I'll add something to the package.

Comment: @Martin: The package was born in order to extend the character set made available by the `utf8` option for `inputenc` without having to look at the Unicode tables. So yes, it works also with pdflatex.

Answer (score 14):

The problem here is that the character must be already active when used for `\def`. The `#1` argument however holds the same character in its previous catcode and this won't be affected by `\catcode`. There is a trick using `\lowercase` but I'm not sure if it works well with non-ASCII characters with normal LaTeX.

You can use `\scantokens` (an eTeX extension available in modern LaTeX versions) to reread the tokens under the current catcodes:

```
\def\subst#1#2{%
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \scantokens{\def#1}{#2}%
}
```

In this case you don't even need to read the second argument, because `\def` will do that for you:

```
\def\subst#1{%
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \scantokens{\def#1}%
}
```

Comment: You're right, \lowercase trick must do (it's exactly what the above-mentioned newunicodechar package uses). Thanks!