# Why can't I use ?

Tags: symbols, unicode, input-encodings, blackboard

I can't figure out why LaTeX won't let me use the  symbol (U+1D53D, mathematical double-stuck capital F). When I try, I get the error `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.`

The input file is UTF-8 encoded. Here is a minimal working (or rather, non-working) example to demonstrate the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
% \newcommand{\eff}[1]{F\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\eff}[1]{\text{#1}}
$ \eff{some} $
\end{document}
```

When using the first variant of `\eff`, everything works (the output is rendered as "Fsome" with an italic F, just as expected). However, if I comment that one out and instead uncomment the second variant, I get the error on line 8 (where I actually use the freshly defined command).

I'm using pdfLaTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 from and on Debian Squeeze (package texlive-latex-base version 2009-11+squeeze1) with no special options at all (just `pdflatex mwe.tex`) to try to render the document.

I find it hard to believe that nobody would have wanted to use this particular symbol in a LaTeX document, so surely it can be done. What am I missing?

Comment: You can use `\mathbb{F}` from the package `amssymb`, see http://texblog.org/2007/08/27/number-sets-prime-natural-integer-rational-real-and-complex-in-latex/

Comment: I would assume that not every symbol defined in Unicode is actually mapped to a glyph that is available in the fonts you are using. This is also going to create portability problems for your source code.

Comment: @N.N. `\mathbb{F}` worked perfectly, thank you! If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ChristianLindig As for source code portability, this is a personal document so portability is not a great concern for me. (And on that note it's worth noting that the particular symbol happens to be mapped to a glyph in the window title bar font I use, but not the font Firefox uses for *active only* tab title text. Go figure. :))

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The fonts used for window decoration by your operating system are not necessarily the ones used by LaTeX to render your document to PDF or PostScript.

Comment: @ChristianLindig Quite right. I just mentioned it as an aside, illustrating your very point about glyph availability in fonts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained at [LaTeX Matters](http://texblog.org/2007/08/27/number-sets-prime-natural-integer-rational-real-and-complex-in-latex/) you can use the package `amssymb` or `amsfonts` together with the macro `\mathbb` and `F` as an argument. Note that you have to use `\mathbb` in [math mode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}            % or \usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\(\mathbb{F}\)

\end{document}
```

If you want to define your own macro like you do in your example this is possible with `\mathbb{F}` too.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now, in my actual document it's claiming that I'm not in math mode, but that's a completely separate issue. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You have to use `\mathbb` inside math mode, e.g. as `\(\mathbb{F}\)`.

Comment: Yes, I had a mix of math mode and text mode, and had got the ordering wrong. That was a trivial fix once I saw the error (which was easy to spot from the differences between my actual document and the MWE).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use  inside your document you can use:

**Edit:**

As egreg pointed out you can use the package [`newunicodechar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) which makes it easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{F}}}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

**Original:**

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\expandafter\def\csname u8:\detokenize{}\endcsname{\ensuremath{\mathbb{F}}}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The command `\ensuremath` is testing whether you are in math mode or not and sets the argument in math mode.

Frank Mittelbach wrote a great explanation about inputenc:

[How can I get utf8 character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69723/how-can-i-get-utf8-character)

Comment: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and then `\newunicodechar{}{\mathbb{F}}` is simpler. :)

Comment: @egreg: Oh a new package ;-) -- However I use `\ensuremath` ;-)

Comment: It's not new (2011/02/18); *don't* use `\ensuremath`: that's a math symbol and ought to be used only in math. I added an answer to Frank's.

Comment: @egreg: The package is new in my repertoire ;-).

Comment: Package [`selinput v1.3`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/selinput-1.3.pdf) (requires [`rempreamblecmds v1.0`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71873949/tex/rempreamblecmds-1.0.pdf)) provides `\DeclareInputUnicodeChar` and `\DeclareInputChar` that also support `utf8x.def` from package `ucs` that has a different syntax for `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. Also these commands can be used after `\begin{document}`. (The PDF files above also contain the DTX files as attachments that are unpacked using plain TeX, release to CTAN later.)