# Make Characters Active via Macro in Math Mode

Tags: macros, catcodes

I am trying to make characters active in math mode, but can't seem to get past the most basic of examples. I would like to define a macro which is passed:

1. the character to make active and
2. the macro that should be executed once that macro is encountered.

The MNWE below attempts to make `=`, `+` and `!` active and color code them. The desired output is that those characters get colored in *math mode* as. Thus, the input

```
a=+b $c=+4+d+3!$ e=+f
```

yields:

[image]

where the characters are *not* altered outside of math mode (the leading `a=+b` and trailing  `e=+f`).

### Notes:

- There is a separate, but related (as it is in the context of active characters) question in the `\MyPlus` macro to detect a binary addition `+` versus a unary positive `+`. Perhaps that should be a separate question?

### Related Questions:

- [Macro to take a character as argument, make it active, then \def it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18134/macro-to-take-a-character-as-argument-make-it-active-then-def-it)
- [How do you define macros to toggle a character active and define a macro for it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184438/how-do-you-define-macros-to-toggle-a-character-active-and-define-a-macro-for-it)
- ["Activate" active characters in argument passed as macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42592/activate-active-characters-in-argument-passed-as-macro)

### Code (non-working):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MakeActiveChar}{%
    m% char to make active
    m% code to execute for this character
}{%
    \catcode`\#1=13\relax%
    \def#1{#2}%
}%

\let\OldEqual=
\newcommand*{\MyEqual}[1][green]{\mathrel{\textcolor{#1}{\OldEqual}}}%

\let\OldPlus+
\newcommand*{\MyPlus}[1][blue]{%
    %\catcode`\+=12% reset catcode so we can use it (not needed with \OldPlus?)
    %% Perhaps this if-then construct should be a separate question?
    %% if binary addition operator
        \mathbin{\textcolor{#1}{\OldPlus}}%
    %% if unary positive operator
    %%  \mathrel{\textcolor{red}{\OldPlus}}%
}%

\let\OldFactorial!
\newcommand*{\MyFactorial}{\textcolor{brown}{\OldFactorial}}%

\everymath{%
    \MakeActiveChar{=}{\MyEqual}%
    \MakeActiveChar{+}{\MyPlus}%
    \MakeActiveChar{!}{\MyFactorial}%
}%

\begin{document}
The ``math'' outside here is just to test that characters are active \emph{only} in math mode:

a=+b $c=+4+d+3!$ e=+f 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps that question about binary should indeed be a different question :)

Comment: For the colour changing, can I point out this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335/86 Based on this, I had a working method that I used happily for many years.

Comment: @PeterGrill If you want a working implementation, just ask.

Comment: Follow-up Question: [Active ! Character Hangs within TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309334/active-character-hangs-within-tikz)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to be careful with the declarations if you load `amsmath`; in the body of the definition, use `\std{<char>}` where you need the old meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}

\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\makeatother


\DeclareMathActive{+}{\mathbin{\textcolor{blue}{\std{+}}}}
\DeclareMathActive{!}{\mathclose{\textcolor{brown}{\std{!}}}}
\DeclareMathActive{-}{\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{\hat{\std{-}}}}}

\begin{document}

a=+b $c=+4+d+3!-1$ e=+f

\end{document}
```

***Don't*** do `\let\OldPlus=+`.

[image]

With Unicode engines (`xelatex` or `lualatex`), the patch must be done differently. Here's a version that copes with all engines.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{iftex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}

\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\iftutex
  \patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\Umathcodenum `\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\else
  \patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\fi
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\makeatother


\DeclareMathActive{+}{\mathbin{\textcolor{blue}{\std{+}}}}
\DeclareMathActive{!}{\mathclose{\textcolor{brown}{\std{!}}}}
\DeclareMathActive{-}{\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{\hat{\std{-}}}}}

\begin{document}

a=+b $c=+4+d+3!-1$ e=+f

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the `-` require special handling? Are there other characters that require special processing?

Comment: @PeterGrill I made a better fix.

Comment: You surely know that ``\expandafter\mathchardef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname=\mathcode`#1`` does similar work like your `\edef`.

Comment: @wipet Yes, thanks for reminding, though.

Comment: There is a bug in `\DeclareMathActive`: it should use two space tokens in the replacement text of `\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname`. eg try `$\std{t}1$` with `\DeclareMathActive{t}{U}`. (or `$\std{+}1$` in the context of your answer; I came here from another question which was linking to it) (you could put a `\relax` at the end of `\std` definition)

Comment: Due to `\newmcodes@` having been recently changed in `amsopn.sty` to better behave with Unicode engines, this (the patch) won't work with `XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work in XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Bolpat Added the modified version.

Answer (score 4):

You can define `\mathdef` declarator and then use it:

```
\input opmac \localcolor

\def\mathdef#1{\mathcode`#1="8000 \bgroup \lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\egroup\def~}}

\mathdef +{\mathbin{\Red\mathchar`+}}
\mathdef ={\mathrel{\Green\mathchar`=}}

aha + $a+b+c=d$

\bye
```

The `\input opmac` is here only for setting colors `\Red`, `\Green` etc. If you are using another macro for colors then use only the second line `\def\mathdef...` in your macros.

Comment: You surely know that ``\mathord{\mathchar`.}`` and ``\mathpunct{\mathchar`,}`` are different from `.` and `,` in math mode. Also ``\mathbin{\mathchar`-}`` is quite different from `-`. Period and comma are taken from the math letters font, whereas the minus is taken from the symbol font.

Comment: When I attempted to use this I got `Illegal parameter number in definition of \mathdef`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems:

`\MakeActiveChar` does `\def#1{#2}` which is not permitted since `#1` is a character that is not active. Here's an alternative with [The `\lowercase` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/the-lowercase-trick)

```
\NewDocumentCommand\MakeActiveChar{mm}
  {\begingroup\lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
   \catcode`#1=12 \mathcode`#1="8000 }
```

Apart from that, you have a missing `=` in a `\let`. The first equal is optional, so `\let\a=\b` is correct, the equal, however, is necessary when you want to let to `=` because if not, it would be treated as the optional one, so

```
\let\originalequal=
```

should be

```
\let\originalequal==
```

And the last part is that by making a character active in math mode, and then doing `\newcommand\plus{\mathbin{\originalplus}}` you get an endless loop like `\def\a{\a}`, so you need to use for instance `` \mathchar`\+ `` or `` \mathchar`+ `` instead.

Complete solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand\MakeActiveChar{mm}
  {\begingroup\lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
   \catcode`#1=12 \mathcode`#1="8000 }

\newcommand*\mathcolor[2]{\begingroup\color{#1}#2\endgroup}

\newcommand*\equal[1][green]{\mathrel{\mathcolor{#1}{\mathchar`\=}}}
\newcommand*\plus[1][blue]{\mathbin{\mathcolor{#1}{\mathchar`\+}}}
\newcommand*\factorial{\mathord{\mathcolor{brown}{\mathchar`\!}}}

\everymath{%
  \MakeActiveChar{=}{\equal}%
  \MakeActiveChar{+}{\plus}%
  \MakeActiveChar{!}{\factorial}%
}

\begin{document}
The ``math'' outside here is just to test that characters are active \emph{only} in math mode:

a=+b $c=+4+d+3!$ e=+f 
\end{document}
```

By the way, I defined `\mathcolor` because `\textcolor` works with `\bgroup`/`\egroup` which create an **ord** atom.

Comment: Can you post a compilable MWE? I get `Missing \begin{document}` when I replace my definition of `\MakeActiveChar` with yours. Also, can you explain why you suggest the double equal? If I use the double equal as you suggest, along with your ``\MakeActiveChar`, I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`.

Comment: Okey, sorry, I just did it without trying, and the error comes from somewhere else. I'll edit.

Comment: Still not a compilable MWE. And again I get `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}` when I replace your `\MakeActiveChar` in the MWE I posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry about the missing compilable example. The point about `\std@minus` in egreg answer is interesting, don't miss it.