# Why does the amsmath package define \std@minus and \std@equal?

Tags: amsmath

The `amsmath` package secures away the original `\mathcode` of the minus and equal signs, and subsequently uses the saved values in the macros that provide the extensible arrows (*e.g.*, `\leftarrowfill@`).  Indeed, at lines 893–900 of `amsmath.sty` we read

```
\mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
\mathchardef\std@equal\mathcode`\=\relax
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
  \mathchardef\std@equal\mathcode`\=\relax
}
\ams@def\relbar{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mathsm@sh\std@minus}}
\ams@def\Relbar{\mathrel\std@equal}
```

Why does it do so?  What problem are the package authors trying to avoid here?

Comment: It's for `\operatorname` and related things.

Comment: @egreg: I see; but why `\std@equal`, then?  As far as I can see, `\newmcodes@` does not redefine the `\mathcode` of `=`.

Comment: I guess it's for symmetry. I'm more concerned with the redefinition of `\std@minus` in `\newmcodes@`, which I deem wrong and, indeed, it can break in certain circumstances, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/4427

Comment: @egreg: Well, now I have another question: I thought half an hour, and I cannot see why `\std@minus` is redefined again inside `\newmcodes@`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

diffs-m.txt contains the remark

> ---Changed \relbar to use \std@minus---otherwise \underleftrightarrow
>   works poorly in a \DeclareMathOperator definition.

and trying this out one can see the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage{amsmath}


\DeclareMathOperator{\test}{\underleftrightarrow{test}}

\begin{document}


\[\test\]

\makeatletter
\def\relbar{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mathsm@sh-}}

\[\test\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is essentialy the same answer that @egreg gave in [his comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352043/why-does-the-amsmath-package-define-stdminus-and-stdequal/352132#comment865115_352043), but the reference to the change log is undoubtebly more useful, and amounts to a “positive” answer. :-)

Answer (score 7):

the comment in the file `amsmath.dtx` reads thus:

> The minus sign used in constructing these arrow fills is smashed so
>   that superscripts above the arrows won't be too high. This primarily
>   affects the `\xleftarrow` and `\xrightarrow` arrows.

since this file has been processed into a pdf file and is included in tex live,
you can look at the details by asking for `texdoc amsmath.pdf`.

implicit in this setting is the knowledge that the minus sign in computer modern
has the same height as the plus, which would certainly affect the positioning
of superscripts unless adjusted.

although not commented explicitly, the equal sign is used as the extender for
two-shaft arrows.

Comment: Of course, I had already read, as carefully as I could, the comments in `amsmath.dtx` before asking this question, but unfortunately they do not explain, as I said in my question, what problem the authors are trying to avoid.  @egreg has answered in his comments, and, by the way, I think that the whole community would benefit if he decided to write a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Let me clarify that I was not asking the reason of the smashing applied to the minus sign: that has always been clear to me.  What I was asking was, why do one need to store away the `\mathcode` value?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- that's a question for the creators of `amsmath`; it wasn't done that way in ams-tex, so it was added when that was "transformed".  i'll ask.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question.  Actually, if I look at `amstex.tex`, I cannot find a redefinition of `\relbar`, so I infere that it uses the definition inherited by `plain.tex`, which is `\def\relbar{\mathrel{\smash-}}` and thus makes no mention of `\std@minus`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton fairly sure you need to ask Michael .. and none of us want to do that just yet. This is not from the days when I and Rainer reimplement amstex for LaTeX, it must have come later

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: So, you are essentially saying that I’ve got no hope of getting a positive answer, aren’t you?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti if you mean by positive answer an authorative answer from the person who wrote that code, then probably no as my guess is that was done by Michael. But to give a reasonable explanation is still possible (so I would not yet give up hope :-))