# 1-1 correspondence in Category Theory

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I have seen that in Category Theory there is a symbol which seems like **two parallel lines with text above and text below**. This means that the thing above corresponds in an 1-1 way with the thing below. I have no idea how to write it in a clever way in latex. I, therefore, want to write something like:

```
\underset{x\in F(C)}{\overset{y_{C}\to F}{=}}
```

[image]

but I want the two parallel line to behave as `\xrightarrow`.

I also want to stack more than two "=", like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you perhaps post an image of the desired result, i.e. an example of how these two parallel lines are exactly used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I add my humble proposal (off-topic) (I think) using the simple `tikz-cd` package to create one of the images made so excellent user **@Schrödinger's cat**. You could put more close `A` and `B`  using the `row sep` and `column sep` parameters used within the environment `\begin{tikzcd} ... \end{tikzcd}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,dash, yshift=0.2ex, "y_{C}\to F"] \arrow[r,dash, yshift=-0.2ex, "x\in F(C)"']
& B 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Here there is the screenshot of the output.
[image]

Comment: @down-voter(s) Always thank you. Is there some mistakes into my code or is it the problem the tag?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! This is just copied from `amsmath.sty` and `mathtools.sty`, and adjusted. **EDIT**: Used [GUM's kind suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517483/1-1-correspondence-in-category-theory/517493?noredirect=1#comment1309018_517493), which is less likely to cause viewer-dependent issues, and is also simpler.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\def\DoubleFill@{\arrowfill@\Relbar\Relbar\Relbar}
\providecommand*\xDouble[2][]{%
  \ext@arrow 0055{\DoubleFill@}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ A\xDouble[x\in F(C)]{y_{C}\to F}B\]
\[ \scriptstyle A\xDouble[x\in F(C)]{y_{C}\to F}B\]
\Huge
\[ A\xDouble[x\in F(C)]{y_{C}\to F}B\]
\[ \xDouble[{\xDouble[\mathrm{presheaf}]{x\in F(C)}}]{y_{C}\to F}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but how can I add more?

Comment: @richarddedekind I do not quite understand what you mean by that. What do you want to add?

Comment: Not really important, but IMHO `\def\DoubleFill@{\arrowfill@ \std@equal\Relbar\std@equal}`, or—better—`\newcommand*\DoubleFill@{\arrowfill@ \Relbar\Relbar\Relbar}`, would be more elegant.  See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/352043) (of mine),

Comment: @GuM Thanks for the heads up, very much appreciated. I will add these options once it is clear what the OP means by adding more.

Comment: By more I mean have more double dashes like the second image in the post.

Comment: @richarddedekind This depends a bit on the context. You can nest these expressions, `\[ \xDouble[{\xDouble[\mathrm{presheaf}]{x\in F(C)}}]{y_{C}\to F}\]`.

Comment: @richarddedekind Remember: the green tick certainly merits the very good user Schrödinger's cat just for honesty: I have used tikz-cd.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, please do not influence users. I think the OP's choice is fine.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I've never influenced anyone. My thought does not come from my mind but from my heart.

Comment: @Sebastiano Your answer is good, there is no reason to unaccept it, and I do not understand the downvote.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Also I have many friends with the downvotes ahahahaah.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes. At least I know my most active downvoter. This user continues to do harm to this site, and I really do not understand why the moderators do not remove him.